# Card style for listview item with a footer on each item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cards

I'm using the code from [this tutorial](http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-make-an-android-card-list/) to create a CardUI-like ListView item, but I need to add to my listview item a footer (just like Google+ app has in its stream view). I have not been able to create the footer (full width and 25dp height) and position its edges to the edges of the Card background (the RelativeLayout I'm using as the footer seems to have a margin).

How can I add this footer (maybe adding to the bg_card drawable code on the link) without margins?

Comment: Search for "android listview custom item layout". There are so many topics on it in Stackoverflow and other websites : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281952/listview-with-customized-row-layout-android

Comment: Well you just have to play with "padding" "layout" and apply some "style" to those layout. Like shadow, rounded corner .. etc and the padding will do the separation between the cells. also you can remove the line between cells.